# Center text in a css border-triangle in email

Tags: css, email, border, css-shapes, text-alignment

I'm trying to generate a triangle using css borders in an Email and put some dynamic text (numbers) in it, but i want to set it to the triangle center, and i cant use positioning because it's being removed from the inline css

I've tried putting the div for the triangle css and the text span in a div container and align it using position - didn't work

```
<div style="<%= MailComponents.create_style('display' => 'inline-block', 'width' => '2px', 'height' => '0px', 'border-radius' => '4px' ,'border-left' => '20px solid transparent', 'border-right' => '20px solid transparent' ,'border-bottom => '30px solid #FC577A', 'color' => '#fff', 'vertical-align' => 'middle', 'line-height' => '28px', 'margin-top' => '-10px') %>">
            <span style="<%= MailComponents.create_style('position' => 'relative', 'left' => '-8px','vertical-align' => 'middle', ) %>">
              <%= some dynamically generated number %>
            </span>
          </div>
```

tried using this trick

```
http://jsfiddle.net/VScFS/57/
```

didn't helped
I'm wondering if this can be done with tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}

.wrapper {
  background: #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 87%, 50% 0%, 50% 0%, 100% 87%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 87%, 50% 0%, 50% 0%, 100% 87%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Use **display:grid** on the parent class and **justify-content: center;** to align it centered horizontally! For reference you can have a look on https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid.asp this link. Hope it'll help

Comment: Tnx! I didn't knew grid is supported in emails, this might be really helpful in the future for other things too.

Comment: @AQUANGEL grid can be removed and replaced with something else but I doubt clip-path is supported in emails. I am pretty sure it will fail

Comment: If you're doing email templates I'd suggest go with a triangle image and on td use align="center", because clip path is not for outlook clients.

Comment: so the justify content center doesnt seem to work in gmail :\
the triangle pic idea sounds good, only problem is our annoying designer who's gonna be like - No! It's you're job to create the triangle! You do it!
Meh

Comment: You can find tons of images on google. Check this solution https://jsbin.com/halosedixi/2/edit?html,output